# Tracing variables passing on a multi class level

Tags: c#, algorithm, functional-programming, roslyn

I am currently working on a C# **static** source code analysis tool with Roslyn and would need some ideas on how to implement/keep track of the path of variables passing.

Given:

```
A = Request.Query;
B = A;
C = A;
someSink(B);
```

I must be able to provide the path from `A->B, B->someSink(B)`. This is the basic idea however the program should take into account complex cases such as variables passing through multi-class files, variables additional i.e `a = b + c`. The scope of the project is a C# project, so any library that works with C# will do, I am currently using Roslyn to parse source codes and doing my analysis with it.

Comment: What if there's a conditional like `if(expr) { do(B); } else { doOther(B); }`. I believe this is an application of the halting problem (how can you determine that there won't be an endless loop somewhere?)

Comment: hmm..with roslyn i can somehow separate the `if` and `else` block into two separate case and do my analysis i guess.